# don't get Http response on Swift by Kotlin Native

Tags: android, ios, ktor, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

I use Kotlin native for our project, I created a native class for https method for get response from `REST API` by `ktor` library, I implemented my code on `Common` layer I use it in `Android` & `iOS` , on `Android` all of the things is OK and get response but on `iOS` don't receive any response while don't get any `Exception`.
I did try and Implemented by 2 diff patterns that first way was used `observer` and second way is `closure` but none of the ways don't work on `iOS`

where is my problem?

in `common` :

```
fun createRequest(bar: (m: String) -> Unit) {
    val client = HttpClient()
    val call = client.call("https://google.com") {
        method = HttpMethod.Get
    }
    bar(call.response.readText())
}
```

on `iOS` project when use :

```
APICoreKt.createRequest(callback: self) { (s) -> Nothing in
 let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100));
 lbl.text = s;
 lbl.textColor = UIColor.black;
 self.view.addSubview(lbl);
 return KotlinUnit();

}
```

Comment: I assume 'cliekt.call' should be in some form of coroutine context. As written you'd be blocking the thread you're calling that on. Also, i'd try logging debug statements instead of adding labels, and add one before and after the call. There are too many ways that addind a label will fail (bad layout, mostly). Please also post how you're calling on android, and what source you used as an example

Comment: @KevinGalliganThanks my bro, but problem is do not receive response on `closure`.

Comment: Could you show more code. Your createRequest fun doesn't seem to compile. Otherwise it must be suspend. Or can you show how you did this? I'm getting similar difficulties